# Why do I get a 500 error calling Changes.Get

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to call as per instructions
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/changeId

and my client is authenticated (as verified by calling different methods).

I get the following 500 error response

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
 [500]
No individual errors

Any idea what this might be? By 500 I take it to mean an issue at the google end.

Here is my code that uses the .net sdk

```
        var changeRequest = service.Changes.Get(id); 

        var changeResult = changeRequest.Execute(); //fails with 500 error
```

Comment: Please add a snippet.

Comment: added. There not much too it really. I get the same issue calling directly via an http client as well (e.g. postman on chrome). I understand that the change id may no longer exist if it has been superseded so I wondered if that was the issue, but then I would expect a 404.

Comment: I should also add that it fails using Google Drive SDKs client built into the documentation. I think it must be generally busted.